# How to achieve that function system() not display the information output

Tags: php

I'am using

```
@system('zip -P password archive.zip workbook.xls');
```

To generate zip archive secured with password, after that i want to redirect user to another page. I can't do it because it display output like: "adding: workbook.xls (deflated 91%)" And i got error 'Headers already sent'.

How can i make this function to not display that output?

Comment: just add this code at the top of your page

Comment: use [output buffering](php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@` sign is for error suppression only, the "channel" your programe sends error message is not the same "channel" the normal output goes. (`stderr`, `stdout`).

There are other functions which do the same as `system` but don't output the `stdout`:

```
shell_exec();
```

http://php.net/system -

```
exec() - Execute an external program
passthru() - Execute an external program and display raw output
popen() - Opens process file pointer
escapeshellcmd() - Escape shell metacharacters
pcntl_exec() - Executes specified program in current process space
backtick operator
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a zip file, there is already a [Zip](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php) module to help you. See  [here](http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php) to have more details and sample.